# How can I distinguish results in ifelse

Tags: r

I want distinguish between $p-values$ for t-test and $p-values$ for Wilicoxon in this code, How can I do that?

`replicate(1000, ifelse(shapiro.test(rnorm(4))$p.value>=0.05,t.test(rnorm(4), alternative = "two.sided")$p.value, wilcox.test(rnorm(4), mu = 0, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value))`

from this code, I will get 1000 p-values for the t-test and Wilcoxon test, if the p-value for the Shapiro-Wilk test is greater than 0.05 we will get the p-value for the t-test and if it is less than 0.05 we will get a p-value for Wilcoxon test my Q is how can I get list or vector of p-values for t-test only from these 1000 p-values

Comment: Can you re-phrase by showing desired results and explain what is the problem of current results? What do you mean by *distinguish*?

Comment: from this code, I will get 1000 p-values for the t-test and Wilcoxon test, if p-value for the Shapiro-Wilk test is greater than 0.05 we will get the p-value for the t-test and if it is less than 0.05 we will get p-value for Wilcoxon test my Q is how can I get list or vector of p-values for t-test only from these 1000 p-values

Comment: Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72135046/edit) your post with your more informative comment (then delete above comment).  But I still do not understand. Your code returns a vector of conditional 1000 p-values.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.table(data = rnorm(4000), sample=rep(1:1000, each=4))
result <- df[, .(s=shapiro.test(data)$p.value, 
                 w=wilcox.test(data)$p.value, 
                 t=t.test(data)$p.value), 
             by=.(sample)]
result[, final:=ifelse(s < 0.05, w, t)]
```